# Push stash to git

Tags: xcode, git, atlassian-sourcetree

Is there a way in Sourcetree to push stash from my computer to another computer? like i have 2 stash saved in my Sourcetree and I want the other developer to have the stashes that I have but i don't want to commit my code.

> Note: Not talking about manual code copy paste